# Basic authentication with Web Load Balancer Openshift

Tags: node.js, basic-authentication, openshift, haproxy

I developed a script in Node.js with a basic authentication and stayed in Openshift.com.

The script works perfectly in an environment without Web Load Balancer. But when exists Web Load Balancer, the script always return 503 error.

The code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.basicAuth('root', '1234'));
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
res.send('Hello World');
});

app.listen(process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080, process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '127.0.0.1');
```

Response error:
    503 Service Unavailable.

Can i use basic auth in Web Load Balancer environment?

Answer (score 1):

What errors are you seeing in your log files? If you are running basic auth on your root context (/), then haproxy probably can not poll your application gears to make sure they are up, since it can't authenticate.  I would recommend adding a route that is NOT protected by auth basic, with a simple page and change your haproxy.cfg to monitor that page to see if your application gears are up.

Comment: I put code and log here: http://pastebin.com/Rvm99yyf ... and statistics report here: http://imgur.com/ULc8P1I

Comment: Yep, so no errors in the log.  Have you tried the recommendation to modify haproxy.cfg and give it a page that it can monitor?

Comment: I put "option persist" and "option redispatch" in haproxy.cfg and works perfectly. But i do not know the mistakes that can come of this setting.